# want to get details of a specific user when clicked on button in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a table which has a button to view the details of specific user.

[image]

I'm retrieving data like this

in html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let userData of user?.users; trackBy: userThumb">
                <td>{{ userData?.first_name }}</td>
```

in ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<User>('backend.url')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

When the view button is clicked, a modal opens and that should show user specific details. How can i achieve this? I tried using `this.user.id`
to grab the user id but that returns undefined

Comment: Can you post the code for the view/edit button to open the modal ... call a function on `(click)` event of the button . pass the id to that function as a parameter. inside the function write the code to open the modal manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the button is inside your table row, following will work:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" (click)="UserClicked(userData)">View/Edit</button>
</td>
```

and in the component.ts file, the UserClicked() function will be like this:

```
UserClicked(userData: any){
    alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
    alert(userData.id);
}
```

If you want to show the details of the clicked user in a popup use the following code:
component.ts file:

```
selectedUser:any
UserClicked(userData: any){
    this.selectedUser=userData;
}
```

in the model popup html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>{{selectedUser.id}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>{{selectedUser.first_name}}</td></tr>
    ......
</table>
```

Comment: [object Object] this is what I'm getting in the alert

Comment: @yer, it means you are getting the object. I have made edits to the answer. Please try that

Comment: yes, now I can see the user details in alert. but could you please help me in showing these in html. I tried to retrieve data like this {{userData?.id}} but couldn't get

Comment: @yer, post the code of the HTML where you want to show it

Comment: @yer, refer the updated answer. You have to store the selected user in a new object and use this in your modal popup to show the details

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [click directive](https://angular.io/guide/user-input). I've made a simple example for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikkgmg) - look at the `.html` file and the `.ts` file.

In your template:

```
<button (click)="onClick(user)">Click</button>
```

In your component:

```
public onClick(user: any) {
  console.log(user);
}
```